# Do Carmo 1.5.18 - Bertrand curves

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, frenet-frame

I am trying to solve the excercise 1.5.18 from Do Carmo's curves and surfaces. Although hints are included in the book I have difficulties with the details.

Part of the Exercise is:

Let $\alpha: I \mapsto \mathbb{R}^3$ be a parametrized regular curve (not necessarily by arc length)
with $k(t) \neq  0, \tau(t) \neq 0, \forall t \in I$. The curve $\alpha$ is called a Bertrand curve if there
exists a curve $\tilde{\alpha}: I \mapsto \mathbb{R}^3$ such that the normal lines of $\alpha$, and $\tilde{\alpha}$ at $t \in I$ are
equal. In this case, $\tilde{\alpha}$ is called a Bertrand mate of $\alpha$ and we can write
$$\tilde{\alpha}(t) = \alpha(t) + r n(t).$$
Prove that

1. $r$ is constant.
2. $\alpha$ is a Bertrand curve if and only if there exists a linear relation
   $$Ak(t) + B\tau(t) = 1, \forall t \in I,$$

where A, B are nonzero constants and $k$ and $\tau$ are the curvature and torsion
of $\alpha$ respectively.

**My Problems:**
I am fine with statement 1.

**Question 1**For statement 2.

One can consider the tangent vector for $t$ for $\alpha$ and the tangent vector $\tilde{t}$ for $\tilde{\alpha}$. Using frenet formulas one can show that $(t \cdot \tilde{t})'=0$. Now if $(t \cdot \tilde{t}) \neq 0$ everything is fine, but if $(t \cdot \tilde{t})=0$ one has that the curvature $k$ of $\alpha$ is constant and given by $k=1/r$.

In this case the only way to find a nonzero constant $B$ is to show that the torsion $\tau$ is also constant.

Is there a way to prove this? If not is there a counterexample? Meaning a curve with constant curvature and nonconstant, nonzero torsion having a bertrand mate?

**Question 2**

For the other direction assume a curve $\alpha$ satisfies $A k + B \tau =1$ with nonzero constants $A,B$.

One then can consider the curve $\tilde{\alpha}:= \alpha + A \cdot n$.
In this case computations using the frenet formulas yield

$$ \tilde{n}= \frac{B k - A \tau}{\sqrt{A^2 +B^2}} \cdot n,$$

where $\tilde{n}$ is the normal vector for $\tilde{\alpha}$. If $B k - A \tau \neq 0$ everything is fine. How to exclude the case $B k - A \tau=0$?

For this I have an example: One can consider the helix $(a \cdot \cos(s) , a \cdot \sin(s) , b \cdot s )$ with $a= b= 1/\sqrt{2}$. Then the relation above is satisfied with $A=B=1/\sqrt{2}$. This implies that the curve $\tilde{\alpha}$ is given by $(0,0,b \cdot s)$ such a curve has no normal vector and thus no good definition of normal line.

So given the relation $A k + B \tau=1$ if $B k - A \tau=0$ for some time $t$ is there another curve, which is a (well defined) bertrand mate?

If no is the statement of the excercise unprecise and if so how to make it rigorous?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should be doing special cases. You've shown there is a constant angle, say $\theta$, between $t$ and $\tilde t$, so write $\tilde t =\cos\theta t + \sin\theta b$. Now what do you get when you differentiate? Remember, of course, that even if $\alpha$ is arclength-parametrized, $\tilde\alpha$ is almost surely *not*.

With regard to your question about the converse, if $A\kappa+B\tau = 1$ and $B\kappa=A\tau$, then $B=B(A\kappa+B\tau) = A^2\tau + B^2\tau = (A^2+B^2)\tau \ne 0$ unless $\tau = 0$. But we're told that the curvature and torsion never vanish.

Comment: (1/2) Regarding Question 1:\par Let me reprhase my question. From Wikipedia (article about differentiable curve) one has: "According to problem 25 in Kühnel's "Differential Geometry Curves – Surfaces – Manifolds", it is also true that two Bertrand curves that do not lie in the same 2-dimensional plane are characterized by the existence of a linear relation ${\displaystyle a\kappa +b\tau =1}$ where ${\displaystyle a,b}$ are real constants and ${\displaystyle a\neq 0}$."\par

In contrast to that Do Carmo claims that both constants are non-zero.

Comment: (2/2) Are these two statements equivalent? Or is the second (stronger) statement false? (Since there exists a non-planar, curve with $\kappa \dot \tau \neq 0$ with constant curvature and non-constant torsion)

Comment: Regarding Question 2: Given a space curve with non-zero curvature and torsion such that the linear relation holds with both constants $A,B$ beeing $\neq 0$. If one Has $Bk=A\tau$ for some $t \in I$. Then your argument would show that $B \neq 0$, which was already implied by the assumption... I think I am missunderstanding, what you have been trying to say. Could you elaborate a little more on that part?

Comment: Ah, I see your point. Yes, I agree that you can always generate a Bertrand mate if $\kappa$ is constant and $\tau\ne 0$. The reverse direction shows that you can write a solution when $B=0$.